# Gravitational law

Tags: newtonian-gravity

[image]

Newtons gravitational law is

$$\ F = \frac{G m M} { r^2 }$$

But I have seen in some cases where they take an angle like $\cos\theta$

Find the force of attraction between the masses $ m $ and $ M $

Comment: The law of gravitational attraction for the diagram you showed is F=G$m_1$$m_2$/(r^2 + R^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gravitational force between two bodies acts in a straight line between the two. So in this case it is 
$F = G \frac{m \cdot M}{r^2+R^2}$ (using Pythagorean theorem for the distance)

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the angle in front of the big mass $M$: $\theta$ and the straight line between $m$ and $M$:$X$. Then $$  \sin(\theta) = \frac{r}{X} \rightarrow X= \frac{r}{ \sin(\theta) } $$ and Newtons force law reads

$$ \ F = \frac{G m M \sin^2(\theta)} {  r ^2}$$

The $r$ in your formula must always be the actual distance of the two masses and is not equivalent to the $r$ in your drawing.

Comment: Tim, you made a mistake: if the angle θ is in front of M, then you have X = r/sin(θ). Maybe you would consider correcting your mistake.

Comment: Oh boy... Yes of course! Thanks for pointing this out, I changed the answer accordingly